# Xpages : Possible to inherit all Select 2 components

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages

I have got Select2 working. Awesome, awesome component.

We have a db with some common elements which we inherit to databases. I would like to add Select2 to this db, so it will be easily available to databases, but don't know how to do that, as you have to put some items in the package explorer.

Any way to do this?

Comment: A better approach is to create a OSGi plugin which distributes the CSJS ressources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. You could set up a central "resources.nsf" with the select2 components and load all the resources you need (manually) from all other databases.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I think this is what I will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you inherit the whole template:

- create a database with all design elements you want to have as default in a database including Select2 parts in WebContent folder
- define this database as template "CommonElements" (or another unique template name) in database properties
  [image]
- define the template "CommonElements" as "Inherit design from master template" in every database where those design elements are needed
  [image]
  and make sure that every additional design element has set "Prohibit design refresh" 
  [image]
  or inherits from a design template.
  In case you have additional elements in WebContent folder set "Prohibit design refresh" flag to those design elements with `File > Application > Set Prohibit Refresh Properity...` too

All design elements including all WebContent folders are inherited from master template when you execute `File > Application > Refresh Design...` or when designer process runs on server.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your users do not have internet access (either fire-walled or offline) you may as well just use a CDN. That way all your users will have a cached version of the download library on all of your sites and you don't have to worry about hosting it somehow.

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/select2

for example

Answer (score 0):

It might also be worth looking at the [Import and Export from Domino Designer project on OpenNTF](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Import%20and%20Export%20for%20Designer). It allows you to create an portlist.xml file, which tells the plugin which files to import. It still requires a manual action to import, but will allow you to overwrite files.

Although using plugins is the place to aim to get to, this is a perfectly valid and good practice method for handling copying all relevant files into an NSF. It's used in XPages OpenLog Logger project on OpenNTF, for the NSF-based option.